# How do I test in a shell script whether I'm running inside Scratchbox2

Tags: bash, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, scratchbox

In the old [Scratchbox](http://scratchbox.org/faq/faqlist.html) one could do something like:

```
if [ -f /targets/links/scratchbox.config ]; then 
    echo "here goes my sbox-dependent stuff" 
fi
```

but what about [Scratchbox2](http://maemo.gitorious.org/scratchbox2), is there a way to find out this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about test the environment variable 'LD_PRELOAD'

```
if [[ $LD_PRELOAD =~ "sb2" ]]; then 
    true # is running under sb2
fi
```